# Can it be done with recursion?

Tags: python, recursion

im trying to make my program run as i want it to, but i have some trouble with that, hope someone can help with that.

I wrote a program that takes a list of chars and assembles them to create words. Word ends when there is a " " in list. So it looks like that:

```
inp = ['r','e', 'e', 'l', ' ', 'y', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 'w', ' ', 'g', 'e', 'l',' ', 'p','e','e','k']
outp = ['reel', 'yellow', 'gel', 'peek']
```

The code looks like this:

```
def mer(inp, outp=[]):
    tail = 0
    for item in inp:
        if item == (" "):
            inp[:tail] = ["".join(inp[:tail])]
            outp.append(inp.pop(0))
            inp.remove(item)
        if ((" ") in inp) == False:
            inp[:] = ["".join(inp[:])]
            outp.append(inp.pop(0))        
        tail +=1
```

And now to get the output (in the case with the input like on top) i need to call mer two times. Is there a way to make it run untill the input list is empty, or maybe use a recursion?

It's just a programming exercise, so it can be probably all done better, but for now thats all i need.

Comment: Yes it can be done with recursion. In general, anything you can write using looping constructs can be written recursively and vice-versa, although you may have to use additional data structures like stacks. P.S. Is this homework? If so, it should be tagged as such.

Comment: Ok, thanks. No, it's not a homework, just my own idea for something to do.

Comment: Thanks for all answers, while the best command to do the job is using join and split (thanks kev, Alasdair), i wanted to know how something like in my question would look like with recursion. Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> And now to get the output (in the case with the input like on top) i need to call mer two times.

The problem with your algorithm is that you are modifying the list while you iterate over it. This is a naughty and unsafe thing to be doing.

After `"reel"` is put into `outp`, `inp` is `['y', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 'w', ' ', 'g', 'e', 'l',' ', 'p','e','e','k']`. But the next character that will be examined by the loop is - at least in the CPython implementation - not the `'y'` of `'yellow'`, but the `'w'`. This is because the iteration internally stores an index (which happens to be in sync with the `tail` variable that you update manually) and uses that to grab elements. The `listiterator` created behind the scenes to implement the for-loop is utterly unaware of changes to the `list` that it's iterating over, and thus can't adjust to keep the "same position" (and who knows what you really mean by that, anyway?).

You can see this for yourself if you add a couple of "trace" `print` statements to the code to show the state of the variables at various points.

Anyway, since the iterator is at the `'w'` at this point, it will find the space next and extract `'yellow'` just fine; but next it will move to the `'k'` of `"peek"`, missing the space after `'gel'`, and it won't run any of the code in your second if-case, either, because the space between `'gel'` and `'peek'` is still in the buffer (you didn't really think clearly enough about the real end condition).

If you really, really want to do everything the hard way instead of just writing `''.join(inp).split(' ')`, you could fix the problem by tracking a beginning-of-word and end-of-word index, slicing out sublists, joining them and putting the resulting words into the output, and **leaving the input alone**. While we're at it:

- functions should use the return value to return data; passing in an `outp` parameter is silly - let's just return a list of words.
- We can use the built-in `enumerate` function to get indices that match up with the list elements as we iterate.
- I have no idea what "mer" means.
- You use way too many parentheses, and comparing to boolean literals (`True` and `False`) is poor style.

So, the corrected code using the original algorithm:

```
def words_from(chars):
    begin = 0 # index of beginning of current word
    result = [] # where we store the output
    for i, char in enumerate(chars):
        if char == ' ':
            result.append(''.join(chars[begin:i]))
            begin = i + 1
    # At the end, make one more word from the chars after the last space.
    result.append(''.join(chars[begin:]))
    return result
```

Comment: Wow, thats actually helpful, thanks. Im just learning so thats why there are so many "odd" things in this code. And You are right, now when i think about it (and have Your solution here) mine was pretty badly thought, and some things didn/t work as intended. There's still a long way for me...

Comment: You're very welcome. Now, please, just write `''.join(inp).split(' ')` and relax. :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `join` and `split`:

```
>>> ''.join(inp).split()
['reel', 'yellow', 'gel', 'peek']
```

---

```
# recursion
from itertools import takewhile

def fun(x):
    if not x:
        return
    y = list(takewhile(lambda i:i!=' ', x))
    yield ''.join(y)
    for z in fun(x[len(y)+1:]):
        yield z

list(fun(['r','e', 'e', 'l', ' ', 'y', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 'w', ' ', 'g', 'e', 'l',' ', 'p','e','e','k']))
```

Answer (score 3):

I know you asked for a method using recursion, but the most pythonic method in this case is to join the characters together, then split them.

```
outp = "".join(input).split(" ")
```

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely use `join` and `split` for this, but since the question specifically asks for a recursive solution, here is an answer that uses one.

**This is meant as an exercise in recursion only, this code should not be used.**

```
def join_split(inp, outp=None):
    if not inp:
        return outp
    if inp[0] == ' ':
        return join_split(inp[1:], (outp or ['']) + [''])
    if outp is None:
        return join_split(inp[1:], [inp[0]])
    outp[-1] += inp[0]
    return join_split(inp[1:], outp)

>>> join_split(['r','e', 'e', 'l', ' ', 'y', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', 'w', ' ', 'g', 'e', 'l',' ', 'p','e','e','k'])
['reel', 'yellow', 'gel', 'peek']
```

Comment: +1 beat me to it. My version is very identical, albeit less pythonic.